# c++ std::getline / std::sort is not working as expected

Tags: c++, std

I have made a little program that loops line by line through file. Everything worked fine with UNIX line endings :

```
 std::ifstream file(filename);
 while (std::getline(file, str))
 {
   std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
   std::cout << str << ""; ----- WORKS as expected
 }
```

When using DOS line endings, the `std::getline` does not return a line. So more trial end error got me thinking, that I should, probably, delimit at " ". And that works:

```
std::ifstream file(filename);
while (std::getline(file, str, ' '))
{
  std::cout << str << ""; -- returns a line 
  std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
  std::cout << str << ""; ----- does not work like the first time
}
```

The second try prints out a line normally but when inputing that line to sort it works unexpectedly. So my question is why is `std::sort` working differently at the second time? My first idea was that maybe variable type is different but that led to nowhere. What am I missing? Is it possible to get it working like in the first code block?

Comment: 'I should probably delimit at spaces' not sure why you thought that might be a good idea, since spaces are not newlines. Your original code should have worked with either unix or dos line endings. What do you mean by 'does not return a line'? What does it return instead?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Works fine with unix and CRLF line terminators on my machine.

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as 'answered', kahvelvahvel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
std::cout << str << "";
```

you should try

```
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

to get a new line in a proper way on all operating systems.

Comment: `std::cout << '\n';` is the proper way on all operating systems. `std::endl` is almost always overkill.

Comment: Using std:: is in many cases "overkill", but it is the STANDARD, that's why its name is "std" :-) .

Comment: My comment isn’t about `std` . It’s about `std::endl`.